# Google Cloud function invoke with http POST - Internal traffic only

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions, google-vpc

I have a Cloud Function (fce_a) that I need to invoke from a different cloud function (fce_b), both in the same GCP project and region. When I set the fce_a to `Allow all traffic` (in `Ingress settings`), it works perfectly (using [this method](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function)). However, when I set the fce_a to `Allow internal traffic only` (in `Ingress settings`) I am getting `Error 403 (Forbidden) 403. That's an error. Access is forbidden. That's all we know.` (mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#serving)).

I've tried using [this method](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call), but it is to be used only for testing purposes and the limits are too restrictive for my usecase.

Any idea on how to call a Cloud function from a different Cloud function if the target function has the `Ingress settings` set to `Allow internal traffic only`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Allow internal traffic only` allows only requests from VPC networks in the same project or VPC Service Controls perimeter. Since cloud Functions are actually running outside of your project, your function `fce_b` can't reach `fce_a` as-is.

To allow this use-case, you'll need to use a [VPC Connector](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc) to connect them to one of your VPC network in your project (you can use the same VPC conector for both functions since they're in the same region). Your `fce_a`, set with `Allow internal traffic only`, will accept traffic coming from that VPC connector. Note that, on your `fce_b`, you'll need to set [Egress settings](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#egress_settings) to match your use case.

Comment: Hi LundinCast, thanks for clearing this up, I didn't know the Cloud Function run actually outside of the project. Out of curiosity - do you know why this method of calling `fce_a` from `fce_b` https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call works even if the `fce_a` has the `Allow internal traffic only` set up?